# How to expose stored images to external web app with REST

Tags: rest-api, files

I have a requirement in which I have to expose some fields of a particular sObject to an external web app. For that I created a RestResource Apex class, with a single HttpGet method in which I make a query against that sObject and return the results.

The problem I have is this: Some of the fields they want are formula fields using IMAGE(). The images used with these fields are stored in the org. (Files home). I understand that all the files stored like that are private, and the IMAGE() formula creates a img tag with a src url relative to the org (sfc/servlet.shepherd/version etc etc). I used these fields inside a visualforce page to render the images, and that works perfectly.

My question is: how can I expose those images to the web app that is consuming my API? If I just expose the fields, they will receive the image tags that won't work as the SRC url is readable only within the platform. Is there a workaround for this?

I thought about maybe generating public URLs for these images and store them on separate fields so the web app can use them as SRC urls. Is this possible?

Comment: I found out reading this article https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2021/05/04/generating-public-url-for-salesforce-files/ that I can generate ContentDistribution objects for each of the images I want to use outside of the org, in which a "ContentDownloadUrl" field is the key to achieving what I want. When I finish testing my solution I'll add the answer